# “Professional contribution” in Australia for the purpose of applying for a Lecturer position

Tags: computer-science, job-search, faculty-application, lecturer, australia

For the purpose of applying for a lecturer position in Australia in computer science, what is actually a "professional contribution"? This phrase occurs among the selection criteria but seems to me way too broad from a purely linguistic viewpoint. According to the text describing the selection criteria, a "professional contribution" is supposed to be separate from experience in research, teaching experience, experience outside university, creative achievements, and technical achievements – they are measured separately.

Comment: Think of it as the "service" side. What adminstration have you done?

Comment: @daaxix There is service in committees of different institutions, there is service in program committees of publication venues, and there is purely admin stuff (e.g., project manager). Which of the above are you speaking about? Is there anything else you are wishing to mention?